# how to replace the bracket only with space in php for the image name

Tags: php, regex

My text variable is

```
$text="518609136Buddha_flag-Copy-(Copy)1.jpg";
```

I want to replace the only ( ) with space like is

```
"518609136Buddha_flag-Copy- Copy 1.jpg"
```

I am use the

```
$text=preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z]+/', ' ', $text);
```

but this output is

```
518609136Buddha_flag-Copy- Copy 1 jpg
```

Comment: Really? What keeps the numbers, the underscore and the dashes in your string if you are only defining the rule for letters? This is what your output would be if you would run what you are saying http://codepad.org/XPMX8DpR

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str_replace`

```
   $text="518609136Buddha_flag-Copy-(Copy)1.jpg";
   str_replace(array( '(', ')' ), '', $text);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
$text=preg_replace('/[()]/g', ' ', $text);
```